# Matlab: plotting a countour plot with smooth shading

Tags: matlab, plot

On page 61 of [this](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~jason/Classes/numwisk/ch10.pdf) pdf, there is figure 10.4.  I am trying to replicate the plot on the lower right corner.  However, in their code they use `contourplot` which isn't in Matlab R2013a.

I have tried using `contour`, `contourf`, `surf`, `surfc`, etc but nothing duplicates their results.

```
%This plots the stability region for RK-4

[X, Y] = meshgrid(-3:.1:1, -3:.1:3);
Mu = X + i*Y;
R = 1 + Mu + .5*Mu.^2 + (1/6)*Mu.^3 + (1/24)*Mu.^4;
Rhat = abs(R);
%contour(X, Y, Rhat)
%contourf(X, Y, Rhat)
%surfc(X, Y, Rhat)
surf(X, Y, Rhat)
```

Is there a plot command that mimics `coutourplot` in their code?  I am guessing they used a different version of Matlab where this command was available.  I am on R2013a.

This is the image from their plot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the PDF tt seems that this was truncated at the value 1. So here's something that will look similar:

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(-3:.01:1, -3:.01:3);
Mu = X + i*Y;
R = 1 + Mu + .5*Mu.^2 + (1/6)*Mu.^3 + (1/24)*Mu.^4;
Rhat = abs(R);
Rhat = Rhat.*(Rhat<1);  %# here I truncate
imagesc([min(X(:)) max(X(:))],[min(Y(:)) max(Y(:))], Rhat)
colormap(flipud(gray))
```

Instead of `imagesc` you can also use `surf` :

```
surf(X, Y, Rhat,'LineStyle','none')
view(0, 90);
colormap(flipud(gray))
xlim([-3 0.5]);
ylim([-3.2 3.2]);
```

[image]

Comment: That is great thanks.  Why did you switch the plotting code?  Is one style better or more efficient?

Comment: I prefer `imagesc` over `surf` if only uniformly spaced 2D grids are involved. In `imagesc` you don't need to specify `view` or line properties, but the `X` and `Y` are assumed to be uniformly spaced ... I don't know if one is more efficient than the other. I can write it back in `surf` if you prefer.

Comment: It doesn't matter which one it is.  I just didn't know if one was better to use.